# TypeScript, React causing errors using forwardRef with props & ref is null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, use-ref, react-forwardref

**Need**: want to pass `props` & `forwardRef` to child component

**MVCE**: this is what I get when I try this on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-typescript-forwardref-with-props?file=components%2Fchild.tsx) - the reference inside the child is null - but no error (like below)...

**But**, the error I am getting in a codebase
[image]

would appreciate an answer/link which can explain this clearly and help resolve this - the examples I saw passed props only or forwardRef only; And on stackblitz, it worked also;

Comment: how is `DivField` defined?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-typescript-forwardref-with-props has the details which work on stackblitz but give an error in my local repo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mixed up the order of the type arguments. `forwardRef` signature looks like this: `function forwardRef<T, P = {}>` where `T` is the ref type and `P` the props type.

Change your code like so:

```
export const DivField = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, any>((props, ref) => {
  console.log("DivField:", props, " -- ref:", ref);
  return <div ref={ref}>this is the div field only </div>;
});
DivField.displayName = "DivField";
```

[Link to Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-typescript-forwardref-with-props-7b9vta?file=components/child.tsx)

Comment: there is no error on stackblitz, the error comes on my local repo... i am unable to recreate the issue on stackblitz as it is...

Comment: your stackblitz configuration used old `@types` with latest `react` and `react-dom`, once I upgraded (see my `package.json`) I got the same error on stackblitz